# Google map with php

Tags: php, google-maps

I followed [this guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3) to set a google map script with php.

I copied everything, created the table as they said and inserted records. When I check the [output of the xml](http://imrip.interhost.co.il/test/phpsqlajax_genxml3.php) everything is fine. When I [check the map](http://imrip.interhost.co.il/test/phpsqlajax_map_v3.html) I can't see the locations.

I didn't provided code since it's a copy of the code in the link I attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the wrong path inside the script:

```
downloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml.php"
```

but it has to be:

```
downloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml3.php"
//----------------------------^
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your load function and ensure php file name is correct when passed to download url function

Answer (score 0):

```
//.php create this form and paste it don't forget float datatype your attribute value in the database
//controller.php is when the action performed on controller.php when the user enter submit button
$action = (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] != '') ? $_GET['action'] : '';
```

switch ($action) {
case 'add' :
doInsert();
break;

```
case 'edit' :
doEdit();
break;

case 'delete' :
doDelete();
break;

case 'photos' :
doupdateimage();
break;

case 'picture' :
UploadImage();
break;
}
function doInsert(){
    if(isset($_POST['save'])){
    if ( $_POST['LATITUDE'] == "" || $_POST['LONGITUDE'] == "" {
        $messageStats = false;
        message("All field is required!","error");
        redirect('index.php?view=add');
    }else{  
        $branch = New Branch();
        $branch->LATITUDE                       = $_POST["LATITUDE"];
        $branch->LONGITUDE                      = $_POST["LONGITUDE"];
        $branch->create();
        message("New Location created successfully!", "success");
        redirect("index.php");
        
    }
    }

}
//to control your navigation or your action add this code in to index.php 
$view = (isset($_GET['view']) && $_GET['view'] != '') ? $_GET['view'] : '';
$header=$view;
$title="Branch";
switch ($view) {
case 'list' :
    $content    = 'list.php';       
    break;

case 'add' :
    $content    = 'add.php';        
    break;

case 'edit' :
    $content    = 'edit.php';       
    break;
  case 'view' :
    $content    = 'view.php';       
    break;

default :
    $content    = 'list.php';
```

}
?>
//add.php find your latitude and longtiude location number and add the required filed



Latitude:

```
                  <div class="col-md-8">
                     <input class="form-control input-sm" id="LATITUDE" name="LATITUDE" placeholder=
                        "latitude." type="text" value="" autocomplete="none">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
<div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for=
                  "LONGTIUDE">Longtiude:</label>

                  <div class="col-md-8">
                     <input class="form-control input-sm" id="BRANCHCONTACTNO" name="LONGTIUDE" placeholder=
                        "Longtiude" type="text" value="" autocomplete="none">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

// view.php add this to display you data from the database
Google Map LocationLATITUDE;?>,LONGITUDE; ?>&output=embed">